# The meeker number sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, number-theory

The Meeker numbers are a 7 digit number in form of \$abcdefg\$, where \$a×b=10c+d\$ and \$d×e=10f+g\$. As an example \$6742612\$ is a meeker number, here \$6×7=10×4+2\$ and \$2×6=10×1+2\$, so it is a meeker number.

Additionally, a Meeker number does not have any leading zeros (so \$a \ne 0\$)

### The Challenge

Your program can do one of the following tasks:

- Take a positive integer \$n\$ and output the \$n\$th Meeker number (0 or 1 indexed, your choice. If 0 indexed, \$n\$ will be a non-negative integer)
- Take a positive integer \$n\$ and output the first \$n\$ Meeker numbers
- Output all 900 Meeker numbers

## Rules

- You may take an [empty input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12681/66833) if you output all Meeker numbers
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Trailing whitespace is allowed.
- If possible, please link to an online interpreter (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run)) to run your program on.
- Please explain your answer. This is not necessary, but it makes it easier for others to understand.
- Languages newer than the question are allowed. This means you could create your own language where the empty program calculates this number, but don't expect any upvotes.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

The first few Meeker numbers are

```
1000000
1000100
1000200
1000300
1000400
1000500
1000600
1000700
1000800
1000900
1101000
1101101
1101202
1101303
1101404
1101505
1101606
1101707
1101808
1101909
...
```

*Thanks to @Adám for the [detailed analysis](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57614863#57614863) and @cairdcoinheringaahing for the editing rework*

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/22038?noredirect=1#comment73269_22038)

Comment: Is our program/function allowed not to terminate (i.e. print/return all the Meeker numbers and then hang forever)?

Comment: @Delfad0r yes it's allowed

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 45 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Full program. Prints all meeker numbers. Requires 0-based indexing (`⎕IO←0`).

```apl
1e6+⍸{(×⌿i⊇⍵)≡10⊥⍵[2+i←0 1,⍪3 4]}¨10⊤¨1e6…1e7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862gv@G6aaaT/q3VGtYWjwqGvpo96t0ZnaRrGajzoXHp7@qGc/WACkWsFQ51HvKmMFk9jaQytAapcAqVSzRw3LjFLN/gON@q8ABgUA) (limited to upper bound of 2 000 000 ― above code works offline)

`1e6…1e7` numbers 1 000 000 through 10 000 000

`10⊤¨` base-10 representation of each (splits digits of numbers into lists of digits)

`{`…`}¨` apply the following lambda to each:

`⍵[`…`]` index the digits of the current number using the following:

`⍪3 4` the column-vector `[[3],[4]]`

`0 1,` prepend a column consisting of `[0,1]` yielding `[[0,3],[1,4]]`

`i←` assign to `i` (for **i**ndices)

`2+` increase by two; `[[2,5],[3,6]]`

`10⊥` evaluate as base-10, using the top row as tens place and bottom row as ones place

`(`…`)≡` check if it matches the following:

`i⊇⍵` select the elements from the digits at indices `i`

`×⌿` multiply the elements of the top row with the elements of the bottom row

`⍸` **ɩ**ndices where true

`1e6+` offset to the first candidate

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>121</s> <s>115</s> 98 bytes

```python
def f(n,t=10):p,q=n%100/t,1+n/100;r=p*q;s=n%t*(r%t);print`t+n/t`+'0'*(r<t)+`r`+`n%t`+'0'*(s<t)+`s`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xDsMgEAR7vyKNZTBIBseVCX@5IkFJc8GwjV@PjyjNaDW70uYT7y@vrT1f6ZYUW0Tv9J7tEXn0zi2w3vAiKZSY5yNU8ZhVGaFDLh8GQXqQmdwk@gFtqJAhWf1d/blKLSmvh6TWjnvH1iF37QI)

On noticing the digits, I observed a pattern and got this constant time solution. Takes n as input (0-indexed) and prints n'th meeker number.

For example, the first 2 digits follow the pattern: 10, 11, 12, ... 99 (with each number occuring 10 times in a row).

*thanks to ovs for -23 bytes*

Comment: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI0/TKlEnyTZP39DAQNtQB0SrGhpYFxRl5pVoJGoBRQ20k0CUdqJWkiaEnwdUoaUBFQOyNf@naRhqcqVpGIEIYxBhAiJAMgA) by porting my Java solution.

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>107</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>74</s></sup> 73 bytes

Saved 8 bytes thanks to the man himself [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!
Saved 5 bytes thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)!!!
Saved a whopping 20 bytes thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%c3%a9goire)!!!

```c
t=10;h=100;a;b;f(n){a=n/h+1;b=n/t%t;a=(a*t*h+b*h+a*b)*t*h+n%t*(h+a*b%t);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdpfbxTJFcbh@/0UFhKSbUDbXVVd3S3HuYnyKQIXxmsWlMS7wpaCgvjqIef3vuewCdodHoaempo6f6p68P2bX@/vv39/vl2Xm4/xsNzc3by/@XD5ePX17vbx54@v1pv38fvzy@ebu9vLu@vn64@v3sf/d9fvr/SHx5fP15f688vnq5tv3/959@nx8uqnrz9dxK9Pj88XD19@f7h/fvjlb@8ubi@@xjvw6/UFWAut0AujsBVmYS8chVNYGS8R/xltaUZfujGWYWzLZsxlGvuyG8dyGOdyBhoTXIxVAwaaxgl0vTww9KrAtubFc82L9zUvPta8@Fy5uPOJF2PVDANNAwa63j0wNE5gWzdj1sv3thpHG8bZ@BSDJVyMVVMNNM0w0DVgYGg@ga3lxbPlxXvLi4@eF5@dizdishir1jDQ1nymr/nMaPnM1vKZ2fOZveczx8hnzsEzkyAvxqpFCDRNNdD1kQNDMwxsPS@ePS/eR158jLz43Lh4J2sWY1WUA23Nv@paw8DQRw5smmFgasDAPk7j2KZxTuJ1kIaLsWp5A02rGuiaamBoDQPbyIvnyIv3LS@Op4xz5@KTvF6MVZkQaFqEQFeUA0OfPbBpDQNTHzmwa4aBowY8j/ikrWqwVQ22qsFWNdiqBlvVYKsabFWDrWqwVQ1SHUtBlcKjKgWoUoAqBahSgCoFqFKAKgWoUhjEI7fMZ6B8BspnoHwGymegfAbKZ6B8BspnZuWRe2YdUNYBZR1Q1gFlHZj1cmUdUNYBZR0f0yOPzA2g3ADKDaDcAMoNoNwAyg2g3ADKDdbNI29rRnBbM4KBXhiFrTALe@EoOIIRiKXgCAYcwYAjGHAEA45gwBGMR0cw4AgGHMF43iMHHMGAIxhwBAOOYMARDDiCAUcw4AgGHMF4I48ccAQDjmDAEQw4ggFHMDDr5Y5gwBEMOIIxc48ccAQDjmDAEQw4ggFHMOAIBhzBgCMYUAR71WCvGuxVg71qsFcN9qrBXjXYqwZ71WCvGuxr7ilAewqP2lOA9hSgPQVoTwHaU4D2FKA9BWhPYRCP3LJSgNYZaJ2B1hlonYHWGWidgdYZaJ2ZlUfu2euAeh1QrwPqdUC9Dsx6uXodUK8D6nV8TI88Mp@B8hkon4HyGSifgfIZKJ@B8hkon1k3jxzQPgi0DwLtg0D7INA@CLQPAu2DQPsg0D5IIDzyzKwDyjqgrAPKOqCsA8o6oKwDyjrgrIvIeuSAzkhAZySgMxLQGQnojAR0RgI6IwGdkYDOSKSKRw6ouoGqG6i6gaobqLqBqhuouoGqG6i6yT2PHNDeDbR3A@3dQHs30N4NtHcD7d1AezfQ3j2qBkfV4KgaHFWDo2pwVA2OqsFRNTiqBkfV4FhztwJaDR61GkCrAbQaQKsBtBpAqwG0GkCrwSAeueWeApQbQLkBlBtAuQGUG0C5AZQbQLnBrDxyz0oBqhSgSgGqFKBKAaoUoEoBqhSgSuFjeuSR/Rmob4Be16hvAPUNoL4B1DeA@gZQ32DdPHJgLbRCL4zCVpiFvXAUHMGZ@QwcwZn5DBzBmfkMHMGZ@cyjIzgzn4EjGM975IAjGHAEA45gwBEMOIIBRzDgCAYcwYAjGC/2yAFHMOAIBhxB3kBvGnAEA45gwBEMOIIBRzBm7pEDjmDAEQz0usYRDDiCAUcw4AgGHMGAIrhVDW5Vg1vV4FY1uFUNblWDW9XgVjW4VQ1uVYM@9STUn3lUfwbqz0D9Gag/A/VnoP4M1J@B@vPW8vQF1kIr9MIobIVZ2AtHwXPuuacAz7nnngI85557CvCce@4pwHPuuacAz3lkpYC10Aq9MApbYRb2wlHwnGMOS8FzDnjOAc854DkHPOd49JwDnnPAcw54zrPnnANroRV6YRS2wizshaPgOcc7LgXPOeA5BzzngOcc8JwDnnPAc45HzzngOR8j5xxYC63QC6OwFWZhLxwFzznGXwqec8BzDnjOAc854DkHPOeA5xzwnAOa86wanFWDs2pwVg3OqsFZNTirBmfV4KwanFWDc80TI1Df4FF9A6hvAPUNoL4B1DeA@gZQ3wDqGwzikVvuVkC9DqjXAfU6oF4H1OuAeh1QrwPqdczKI/c8fQH1Z6D@DNSfgfozUH8G6s9A/RmoP/MxPfLIPQVoTwHaU4D2FKA9BWhPAdpTgPYUoD2FdfPIW1YKaIVeGIWtMAt74Sg4gjM7P3AEZ3Z@4AjO7PzAEZzZ@Xl0BGd2fuAI7iMjGHAEA45gwBHcR0Yw4AgGHMGAI8jJb82LHcF4I48ccAQDjuAxMoIBRzDgCAYcwYAjGHAEA45gzNwjBxzBc8sIBhzBgCPIXUrLix3BgCMYcAQDiuBeNbhXDe5Vg3vV4F41uFcN7lWDe9XgXjW4Vw3ua373BXR@5lHnZ6DzM9D5Gej8DHR@Bjo/A52fgc7PulHQyC3v6IFWA2g1gFYDaDWAVgNoNYBWA3g1et6nAN2nAN2nAN2nAN2nAN2nAN2nAN2nAN2nAN2n8DE98sjTF1BuAOUGUG4A5QZQbgDlBlBuAOUG6@aRt9xTgPozUH8G6s9A/RmoPwP1Z6D@DNSfCYRHnlkpQJUCVCn7zEoBqhSgSgGqFKBKAaoUIuuRA7rvBq3@SvfdQPfdQPfdQPfdQPfdQPfdQPfdpIpHDqhvAPUNoL4B1DeA@gZQ3wDqG0B9A6hvkHseOaDvN4C@3wD6fgPo@w2g7zeAvt8A@n4D6PsNoO83jqrBo2rwqBo8qgaPqsGjavCoGjyqBo@qwaNq8Fjzrg0o63hU1gFlHVDWAWUdUNYBZR1Q1gFlHYN45Jb3VkDrDLTOQOsMtM5A6wy0zkDrDLTOulHQyD13K6DqBqpuoOoGqm6g6gaqbqDqBqpuPqZHHnmfApTPQPkMlM9A@QyUz0D5DJTPQPl8bHn6AmuhFXphFLbCLOyFo@AIztxTgCM4c08BjuDMPQU4gjP3FB4dwZl7CnAE96wU4AjuWSnAEdyzUoAjuGelAEdwz0oBjmC8h0cOOILHzAgGHMGAIxhwBAOOYMAR9Cc0HMGYuUc@94xgwBEMOIIBRzDgCAYcwYAjeO4ZwYAieFYNnlWDZ9XgWTV4Vg2eVYNn1eBZNXhWDZ5Vg@ea3zEC9Toe1euAeh1QrwPqdUC9DqjXAfU6oF7HIB655YkRKDeAcgMoN4ByAyg3gHIDKDeAcoNZeeSe330B7d1AezfQ3g20dwPt3UB7N9DeDbR38zE98shzHVDWAWUdUNYBZR1Q1gFlHVDWAWUd6@aRt7xP0TlozWe0DwLtg0D7INA@CLQPAu2DQPsggfDIM09fQPkMlM9A@QyUz0D5DJTPQPkMlM9E1iPvuacA7SlAewrQngK0pwDtKUB7CtCeArSnkCoe@chKAaoUoEoBqhSgSgGqFKBKAaoU4EqJ3PPIAZ2RgM5IQGckoDMS0BkJ6IwEdEYCOiOBOCN9u9E/3d9/vPt8HY8P939/@Ox/u3/x9stf29sv51/i/@3F64v//XN/ka/78Nvni0v@3f8xXrLcxG9/unj69O@H3z5c1k8CXP2cT1z/eObm4tWrxysN4J8cqJ8eeIpR@GmEm/979iGe/fFzBY/v/vjL3z/HX3@4fPHyl4s3f76Ix5dPbx9jqo@vL55e//g0T7e3D@9yyG8/ffv@n/sP/7j79en7m3/9Fw)

Inputs \$0\$-based \$n\$ and returns the \$n^{\text{th}}\$ Meeker number.

Comment: `a*b%10*e++` without parentheses should be fine.

Comment: [99 bytes](https://tio.run/##Lc1RCoMwEIThqwRByJoU176VaQ6za4kINk2kb@LZ0whl4IfvaebbvElaahUoMgqipSN@diuB8RidE9BFbdTnxAzK@5q@0Xb9q43v/5rOi89Bx4l9HoL4EtS5/lLLUAhnfcuaLJnDtBOYs/4A)

Comment: @Arnauld Very nice - thanks! :D

Comment: a;b;p;q;main(){for(;b%100||9/++a;)printf("%d%d%02d%d%02d ",a,p=b/10%10,p*=a,q=b++%10,p%10*q);}

Comment: @tsh Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYpNCsIwEIX3PUUoFGYai8lSxt7EzSSaEqijxIqLkqsbU3Xz/r7nBz@zTKUwOQoguPIoe2uMtuS@qbOG0mV5JgHuKzDabaa5d/jrUi89/LeakXKJ1Fw5CuDaKBVuCeJoKB4PpqrWqLZZqXuKsgRou/NJ2p0KEBGpktzk8vZh5ulRhtcH). Prints the nth number. It's a dumb port of [my Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223556/16236), so it might require some adjustment to make the entry valid and/or golf it further.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Sweetness - thanks! :D Saved another 4 bytes (credited to you) by switching to `gcc` to get rid of the `return`. Previously needed `clang` to make the `printf` parameters evaluate left-to-right. Old version was useful for generating testcases! :)))

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 65 bytes

```javascript
for(i=99;i<999;print((e-i+'0'-a*b+e)*~99+a*b%10*e))[a,b,e]=++i+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpNCoAgEEDh04Q/o1DLoTpJtNCaYIpKVII2Xd3cPL7F293j0hI5ZJsCrxTP@zroLWW7o@QRsecBa0PkK0tJlkG0wjrtgZT@EKGy6VpNSk3OeEPzCFAnUcoP)

For example, when `i == 267`:

```javascript
i=267;
[a,b,e]=i+'';
print([a, b, e]); // ["2", "6", "7"]
print(e-i); // -260
print(e-i+'0'); // "-2600"
print(a*b); // 12
print(e-i+'0'-a*b); // -2612
print(e-i+'0'-a*b+e); // "-26127"
print((e-i+'0'-a*b+e)*~99); // 2612700
print((e-i+'0'-a*b+e)*~99+a*b%10*e); // 2612714
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYzNCoJAFEb3PsVlIPzXcQhFxB6gRS1aigu1SaZMRSV006ubOpYVtblczjl85@gW1UnFykavS3ak1bXIL7Try4rlDfjQgr@BpMjrIqNGVqTS9rDfGXUz6JSdOqmVZa9nPrEdTwgiLdZo6DNVFD1hWpAGBrEGNJQ9ME0IEEEaIHs8DgrniOqMa53YeGGqiEXO0SgwmlWkxBxb5DPWX2bof0mVLnsWcZ6DX4lyd13eTRXG/zN1eFcWVuhbb637/gE)

---

## JavaScript (Firefox), 72 bytes

```javascript
for(f='%.2d',i=99;i<999;console.log(a+b+f+e+f,a*=b,a%10*e))[a,b,e]=++i+f
```

Thanks [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) for pointing out that Firefox support `%.2d` for padding zeros.

Comment: Sad story: Firefox support `%2d` but not `%02d` in `console.log`... All other browsers (Opera 12, IE 11, Chrome, Edge) does not support `%2d` in `console.log` at all.

Comment: Nice, you didn't bruteforce it!

Comment: @tsh Use`%.2d` for leading zeros.

Comment: @Neil Aha, it works! Thanks for pointing out that. But after more modification, it seems using `console.log` not saving bytes any more..

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>101</s> <s>91</s> <s>71</s> 69 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe, amazingly within <5 mins of posting*

```r
outer(10:99,0:9,function(a,e,d=a%%10)((a*100+a%/%10*d)*10+e)*100+d*e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7@0JLVIw9DAytJSB0jopJXmJZdk5udpJOqk6qTYJqqqGhpoamgkahkaGGgnquoDuVopmkCedqomWCxFK1Xz/38A)

---

The original version - inspired by and taking a similar approach to [Manish Kundu's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223378/95126), and also golfed-down from 101 to 96 bytes by Giuseppe:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 96 bytes

```r
z=c(0,'')
paste0(a<-100:999%/%100,b<-0:99%/%10,z[(a*b>9)+1],d<-a*b,0:9,z[((f=d%%10*0:9)>9)+1],f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8o2WcNAR11dk6sgsbgk1UAj0UbX0MDAytLSUlVfFcjSSbLRBXHBPJ2qaI1ErSQ7S01tw1idFBtdIEcHKAsS10izTVEFqtEC8jWhKtI0//8HAA)

(Note on `z=c(0,'')`: we need to 'pad' the single digit products with a zero when building our text string, and this needs to be done in way that's compatible with the vectorized `paste` function.  So `z[(a*b>9)+1]` is equivalent to (but shorter than) `ifelse(a*b>9,'',0)`)

Comment: If you're going to only use two loops, may as well use `outer` for [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7@0JLVIw9DAytJSB0jopJXmJZdk5udpJOqk6qTYJqqqGhpoamgkahkaGGgnquoDuVopmkCedqomWCxFK1Xz/38A)

Comment: @Giuseppe - I don't think I can even type that fast, let alone golf a computer program!  Thanks!

Comment: Haha, well, I was looking at your 96 byter (again, still can't figure out how to shorten it on a fundamental level) and saw you had made an edit, and it kinda all just went from there.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 27 bytes

```
föΛo§=oΠ←od→C2§e←→X4dfo=7LN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@3wtnOz8w8tt80/t@BR24T8lEdtk5yNDi1PBXKAzAiTlLR8W3Mfv///AQ)

returns the list of all meeker numbers. It's horribly inefficient, so [here's a version which starts from 1e7, and shows the first n values.](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxLTD287Nzj@03Db/3IJHbRPyUx61TXI2OrQ8FcgBMiNMUh41NXIBFebbmvscWggUMjQAg////xsaAAA)

**EDIT:** corrected the answer after Dominic Van Essen found a bug.

Comment: I wonder if anyone isn't going to brute-force it...

Comment: What about non-7-digit numbers where the first-4 and last-4 digits meet the product-digits condition?  I think this will mistakenly output them as meeker numbers: [try it](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxLTD287Nzj@03Db/3IJHbRPyUx61TXI2OrQ8FcgBMiNMUh41NXIdWghkGxoYGIDw////DQ0A)...

Comment: hm, I'll change it.

Comment: Even with ```¡→!7İ⁰``` you'll still get >7-digit numbers ([try this](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DCR22TFI2ObHjUuOH/fwA) to get the idea)...

Comment: ok, time for more inefficiency

Comment: Since all Meeker numbers have 7 digits, it's a finite list, right?

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```perl
/(.)(.)(.(.))(.)/,$1*$2-$3||$5*$4-$'||say for 1e6..1e7-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQ08TjIAEiKGvo2KopWKkq2JcU6NiqqVioquiXlNTnFipkJZfpGCYaqanZ5hqrmv4//@//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYGAA)

Outputs the entire list of Meeker numbers.

Comment: The first `||` can be just `|` and `1e7-1` is the same as `9x7` for [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQ08TjIAEiKGvo2KopWKkq2Jco2KqpWKiq6JeU1OcWKmQll@kYJhqpqdnWWH@//@//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYGAA).

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>32</s> 24 bytes

```
θsт+2£DSPsт*+ìD2.£SPsт*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3I7ii03aRocWuwQHAFla2ofXuBjpHVoM5f3/b2xiCgA) Outputs the \$n^\text{th}\$ Meeker number.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 86 bytes

```javascript
_=>[...Array(1e7).keys()].filter(x=>(s=x+'')[0]*s[1]==s[2]+s[3]&&s[3]*s[4]==s[5]+s[6])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcjbCsIwDADQv9kSh8F5fcrA7yhBykxlWlZphmxfX50v5@E8/cdbn4f3tB3TXUvgcuPOEdE1Z79Aqxekly4GKBSGOGmGmTswnpu6RreTjblWmM3tpTF3kKpa/e3xv6d1z4KlT6OlqBTTAwIgli8)

I feel like this is too long.

## Explanation

Basically, this gets all numbers from 0 to 9999999, coerces each to a string and checks character-wise.

One of Javascript's quirks is that multiplied strings are coerced to numbers, but  added ones are not. So `'5'*'6'` is 30, but `'5'+'6'` is 56.

So in `s[0]*s[1]==s[2]+s[3]`, the first half is a number which is the product of the first two, the second half is the two cocatenated into a string, and using == allows type conversion.

Since it gets the numbers from 0 to 9999999, the numbers from 0 to 999999 are invalid and shouldn't be counted. Fortunately, since the number is coerced to a string, taking its 6th (0-indexed) character  will return undefined, so it will be counted as invalid.

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFJDoAgDADA3yDYSvSkCfYlxgOyBQ@VIPH7OHPbz76u5tKmb@s9PlUyzQaA9yWsRsnD4oUOPQaMmE46tNYMw3CiA09kx0tESER@DEKUmrlJVqr3Hw) (full V8 program)

Comment: @Arnauld I knew I was doing something wrong.

Comment: You can save one byte by using bitwise AND instead of regular AND. So `_=>[...Array(1e7).keys()].filter(e=>(s=e+'')[0]*s[1]==s[2]+s[3]&s[3]*s[4]==s[5]+s[6])` or similar

Comment: @ophact Thanks. I've kind of given up - see Arnauld's comment above.

Comment: `for(i=0;++i<1e7;){[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]=''+i;a*b==c+d&d*e==f+g?alert(i):0}` for 68 bytes. *hint: don't run this as you will have to click through 900 alert boxes.* **idea stolen from @Arnauld**, all I did was change `[...''+i]` to `''+i` because you can also destructure from strings

Comment: @ophact Arnauld used print so no alerts. Nice though!

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>82</s> <s>80</s></sup> 76 bytes

- -6 bytes thanks to [kops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101474/kops), for rearranging things and proposing a better interpretation of the rules :P

```hs
[n|n<-show<$>[1..],[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]<-[read.pure<$>n],a*b==10*c+d,d*e==10*f+g]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc2xDsIgFEDRX2Ho1D6adjQBv0AnRyTmFR7UtEUCNC5@u2h0u8NJ7ox5oXWtG9FCSV6rCq8geJ4fT9Ec1dj3GhTCBAYsEDjwWnCVCG0f90RfEzRgO0k5Dq3pLNiWfu06r@uG9yA3jOcbi3u5lHQKrGEFF2KHYWD/aX0bt6LPlZsYPw)

The list of all Meeker numbers, represented as strings.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 80 bytes

```hs
[n>>=show|n@[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]<-mapM([0..9]<$id)[1..7],a>0,a*b==10*c+d,d*e==10*f+g]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc29DsIgFEDhV@ngoPSW0MmYFOID6OSIxNzy0zYFJKXGxWcXo25n@XJGzLP1vgRrZ7vwa5FRCJ7H@/MVjxKhBw0GLDgYVNcETOetZJQeVLeZzE62lO4VoGCApOe8ZUTXBgyxv3b1oErAKfIvvFXpsV7W5RSr/628tfM45NLolD4)

Comment: I'm not at all sure if this is allowed by the rules, but I got to [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jc2xDsIgFEDRX2Ho1L42dDExKX6BTo6I5hVeW1NAAjQufrtodLvDSe6CaSVriyNaKYpLkf7lhzYtj@dQHWTPr7uuUyARRtBggGCCWQ2tjISmC1ukL/MKsB6F6HmtGwOmpl9PzayKw7sXDsPpxsKWzzkePatYxpXYnnP2/5a3nizOqbQ6hA8) by combining your solutions and not terminating.

I guess this should at least be the shortest if you were to naively convert to doing one of the other tasks (nth term or first n terms).

Comment: [76](https://tio.run/##Jc2xDsIgFEDRX2Ho1D6adjQBv0AnRyTmFR7UtEUCNC5@u2h0u8NJ7ox5oXWtG9FCSV6rCq8geJ4fT9Ec1dj3GhTCBAYsEDjwWnCVCG0f90RfEzRgO0k5Dq3pLNiWfu06r@uG9yA3jOcbi3u5lHQKrGEFF2KHYWD/aX0bt6LPlZsYPw), actually (missed your trick of just starting at `1`). I guess this puts it even with your first solution at 80 bytes even if you terminate at `10^7`.

Comment: @kops I wasn't sure either, but your trick still saves 2 bytes from my second solution. I don't know what the general rules about termination are for finite sequences, I'll probably ask the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>20</s>  19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [Makonede](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94066/makonede) (Output first \$n\$ instead of the \$n^\text{th}\$.)

```
DḌ,PƊƝFḊm3⁼2/Ạ
ȷ6Ç#
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer, \$n\in[1,900]\$, that yields the first \$n\$ Meeker numbers

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//ROG4jCxQxorGnUbhuIptM@KBvDIv4bqgCsi3NsOHI////zIw)** Very slow so will probably time out for \$n \gt 36\$.

#### How?

```
ȷ6Ç# - Main Link: integer, n
ȷ6   - 10^6
   # - find the first n integers starting at 10^6 for which:
  Ç  -   call Link 1

DḌ,PƊƝFḊm3⁼2/Ạ - Link 1: integer, x   e.g. 9218756
D              - digits (x)                [9,2,1,8,7,5,6]
     Ɲ         - for neighbours:
    Ɗ          -   last three links as a monad f([a,b]):
 Ḍ             -     from digits ([a,b])   [92, 21, 18, 87, 75, 56]
   P           -     product ([a,b])       [18, 2,  8, 56, 35, 30]
  ,            -     pair                  [[92, 18], [21, 2], [18, 8], [87, 56], [75, 35], [56, 30]]
      F        - flatten                   [92, 18, 21, 2, 18, 8, 87, 56, 75, 35, 56, 30]
       Ḋ       - dequeue                   [18, 21, 2, 18, 8, 87, 56, 75, 35, 56, 30]
        m3     - modulo-3-slice            [18,        18,        56,         56]
           2/  - pairwise reduce by:
          ⁼    -   equal?                  [1,1]
             Ạ - all?                      1
```

Comment: What prevents this from incorrectly outputting non-meeker numbers for indices >900 (or doesn't that matter?)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I am 99% sure that's undefined behavior.

Comment: By the way, -1 by removing `Ṫ` to output the first \$n\$ Meeker numbers.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I was assuming we may Do Anything when given invalid input.

Comment: @Makonede Oh yeah, silly me; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>34</s> <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
₁`:%10¹d₁↑2d+100
§+o*100doΠ↑_2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1FTY4KVqqHBoZ0pQOajtolGKdqGBgZch5Zr52sBGSn55xYAReON/v//b2xiCgA) or [Get the whole meeker sequence](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8WiDpYHB/0dNTQlWqoYGh3amAJmP2iYapWgbGhhwHVquna8FZKTkn1sAFI03@v8fAA)

*Calculates* (rather than brute-forcing) the `n`th meeker number.

Not as short as [Razetime's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223369/95126), but inspired by [A username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/a-username)'s comment "I wonder if anyone isn't going to brute-force it..." underneath it.

A nice feature of this approach is that it actually completes the task, although there were obviously never any brownie-points on offer for achieving this questionable goal…

**How?**

```
§+o*100doΠ↑_2      # helper function (₁):
                   # takes a list of digits, and returns the number formed 
                   # by appending the product of the last 2 digits.
§+                 # Add together        
        oΠ         #  product of
          ↑_2      #  last 2 digits, and
  o*100            #  100x 
       d           #  the number represented by the digits

₁`:%10¹d₁↑2d+100   # main program:
            +100   # add 100 to the input,
           d       # get the digits,
        ₁↑2        # apply helper function ₁ to the first 2 digits,
       d           # and convert this back into a list of digits;
 `:                # now append with   
   %10¹            # the input modulo 10 = last digit of input;
₁                  # finally apply helper function ₁ to the result
```

Comment: [thanks lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223423/94066)

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 75 bytes

```java
n->{int a=n/100+1,b=n/10%10;return(a*1e3+b*100+a*b)*1e3+n%10*(100+a*b%10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU7LasMwELz7K5YUg/yIKpNT67pQKIUeekpvpQfZlsI6tmSkdSCEfLsrO@lhmZmdfUwnT3LbtccZh9E6gi5oPhH2XE@mIbSGp2XU9NJ7@JJo4BIBjFPdYwOeJAU4WWxhCB7bk0Nz@PkF6Q4@WUcBPg1923cbVtTH/SToCmazfb2gIZCVeSyEyIq8XllciNIpmpxhMi3ULqvTxZZpnazShIGU3VuBJ@V1LtdP2jpgy0mECkQZ4AWexEKy7D8NwP7sSQ3cTsTHEJc02wxKHZWDh7h9hpgLHZtNDpiD5nIc@/Obv8VnmCS3T9doqev8Bw)

Outputs the n<sup>th</sup> number, 0-indexed.

### Credits

- -2 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

Comment: -2 bytes by outputting as double and changing the `1000` to `1e3`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
Ｆ…χ¹⁰⁰Ｆχ⟦⪫⟦ι﹪%02dΠικ﹪%02d×﹪Πιχκ⟧ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1BCgIxDEWvEgpCAhFSt95AEETcDbMonVGDtYE6ev04I4ILl/@9Bz9fU8uWivvZGuAx1cuIURiiCBF8YBSCQ9M6Ybczrdgpw96GZzEMK9kMgWc97zyhEjHc/vRJ7@MDv/DXLi9LT9QzhEA9bd19/Spv) Link is to verbose version of code. Prints all 900 Meeker numbers. Explanation:

```
Ｆ…χ¹⁰⁰
```

Loop over all possible first pairs of digits.

```
Ｆχ
```

Loop over all possible fifth digits.

```
⟦⪫⟦...⟧ω
```

Print the following items on one line and then move to the next line.

```
ι
```

The first two digits.

```
﹪%02dΠι
```

The product of the first two digits, left zero-padded to 2 digits.

```
κ
```

The fifth digit.

```
﹪%02d×﹪Πιχκ
```

The last two digits.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 58 bytes

```
A(/%Q100T+1/Q100)A(*GH*%*GHT%QT)s[+T/QT*"0"<GTG%QT*"0"<HTH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31FDXzXQ0MAgRNtQH0RrOmpouXtoqQKJENXAEM3iaO0Q/cAQLSUDJRv3EHdVKNMjxOP/fwtLSwA)

Same as my Python solution. `A` assigns the two provided elements to the variables `G` and `H` respectively. `Q` is the input (zero-indexed).

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 103 bytes

```scala
Stream from 1 map "".+filter{x=>x.size==7&&x.map(_-48).sliding(4,3).forall{x=>x(0)*x(1)==10*x(2)+x(3)}}
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/09IQr03XSVWZtsGNkF8Kmg)

A pretty straightforward answer. You can treat it like a function giving the nth Meeker number (0-indexed) or as a list of all Meeker numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 65 bytes

```
999*¶

$.`
G`...

;
+`(.);(.)
$1$2,0$.($1*$2*
;|,0?(?=...,|..;)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8vS0lLr0DYuLhW9BC73BD09PS4uay7tBA09TWsg5lIxVDHSMVDR01Ax1FIx0uKyrtExsNewtwUq1KnR07PW5Pr/HwA) Outputs all 900 Meeker numbers. Explanation:

```
999*¶

$.`
```

Insert all the numbers from `0` to `999`.

```
G`...
```

Keep only the 3-digit numbers.

```
;
```

Insert separators around all of the digits.

```
+`(.);(.)
$1$2,0$.($1*$2*
```

Multiply the first and second digits, then multiply the last digit of the result by the third digit, inserting an extra `0` prefix for each result.

```
;|,0?(?=...,|..;)
```

Delete unnecessary separators and `0`s.